# Shortest Javascript shorthand for if statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement

What is the shortest way(least characters) to do the equivalent Javascript 'If Statement' for:

```
if(value) {
  value = value.toString();
}
```

Comment: Shorter does not always read better.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is almost like code golf. (there is nothing wrong with the code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
value = (value) ? value.toString() : value;
```

But I think it is not a very good example (value?, value.toString?)

Another way, but not the same, that may help you:

```
value = value && value.toString();
```

Comment: I think your second example works fine and is the shortest so I up-voting you, since it appears you were the first, thanx all

Answer (score 5):

You can use an logical && as it will return the value of [one of the operands](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-binary-logical-operators).

```
value = value && value.toString()
```

So if `value` is truthy then it will evaluate `value.toString()` and return that else it will return `value`

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
value && (value += '')
```

The && operator expects two arguments and returns:

- First one that evaluates to false (is false-y), or
- Last one, otherwise

So, the expession `(value+='')` will only be evaluated when `value` is existent.

Further, javascript typecasts an integer to string when we use the `+ operator`. Hence,  the expression `(value+='')` will convert `3`(Integer) to `"3"`(String)

Comment: Why a downvote ? This is solving the purpose and is the shortest shorthand indeed!

Answer (score 0):

value = value && value.toString();

if value is true it will evaluate value.toString() and return the result,else it will return value